# jquery for loop on click image swap

Tags: jquery, image, for-loop, swap, src

I've created a for loop of images. I would like each image to swap with another image on click individually. Here's the jQuery I've written so far:

```
for ( var i = 1; i < 50; i++) {
  $('article').append('<div class="ps-block" id="' + i + '"><img src="img/bw/' + i +   'bw.png"></div>');
}

$('img').click(function() {
  var imgid = $(this).attr('id');
  $(this).attr("src", "img/color/" + imgid + ".png");    
});
```

I also attempted to use this code inside the for loop after the append, but `i` ends up returning 50 every time you click since the loop has already ran:

```
$('img[src="img/bw/' + i + 'bw.png"]').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src", "img/color/" + this.id + ".png");    
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Problem solved! Arun's solution worked, I had just neglected to select the id of the parent of the image that had been clicked. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the `img` element does not have `id` set, you have the `id` set for the parent `div` element.

```
$('img').click(function () {
    var imgid = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    $(this).attr("src", "img/color/" + imgid + ".png");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9xKHs/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and rap your code in [DOM ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/9xKHs/3/)

As elements are added dynamically you can not bind events directly to them .So you have to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('article').on('click', 'img', function () {
        var id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
        $(this).attr("src", "img/color/" + id + ".png");
    });
});
```

Syntax

```
$( elements ).on( events, selector, data, handler );
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the $(document).ready() method to contain the function you wrote above.

Comment: It was already contained, I just left it out since I knew it wasn't the issue. The looped images were already appearing at least.